# How to add inline computing in knockout data-bind?

Tags: html, knockout.js

How can I build a hyperlink like this?

```
<a href="#/detail/3">View Detail</a>
```

Can I do something like the one below?

```
<a data-bind="href: '#/detail/'+id">View Detail</a>
```

I just don't think it is necessary to created a computed observable for `href`. There must be an easy way, some inline markup.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured it out by trying different things:

```
<a data-bind="attr: {href: '#/view/'+id()}">View Detail</a>
```

It just works!

Comment: This indeed works, only drawback is that without creating an observable you can't unit test that your anchor tag value is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this:

```
      <a data-bind="href: '#/detail/'+id()">View Detail</a>
```

But, in order to make a good practice of MVVM pattern i suggest you to create a computedObservable